# Spark SaveAsTextFile() in Scala IDE creating "temporay->0" folder structures , not the one mentioned in function

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, exception, ide

Using Scala IDE to save output in a file with the below code

---

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object RDDWithCSVFile {
  def main(args : Array[String]): Unit={
    val spark=SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("Creating RDD with CSV Files")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

    val rdd= spark.sparkContext.textFile("src/test/resources/datasets/CDH_Wellness.csv")

    val header=rdd.first()

    val csvwithoutheader= rdd.filter(!_.contains(header))

    val elements= rddwithoutheader.map(line => {
      val colarray = line.split(",")
      Array((colarray(0),colarray(4),colarray(5),colarray(10))).mkString(" ")

    })

      elements.saveAsTextFile("C:/Spark_Files/RDDWithCSVFile/New Folder") 
  }
}
```

---

But instead of creating the output file-> part-00000,SUCCESS , its creating the below folder structure

C:\Spark_Files\RDDWithCSVFile\New Folder_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20200526184311_0006_m_000000_0

Under this directory ,only part-00000 is created but its an empty file.
No SUCCESS file is created.

Can anyone provide any suggestion.

Comment: I see _temporary will only created when the files are writing , once the writing is done it will rename or remove _temporary folder. can refresh folder once & check if it is created actual location ??

Comment: `rddwithoutheader` you map over it, but what is it? Is it `csvwithoutheader`?

And try dropping spaces from folder paths.

Comment: And you could try printing the size of your data you are trying to write. Maybe the elements RDD is empty

Comment: Srinivas -   C:\Spark_Files\RDDWithCSVFile\New Folder\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20200526184311_0006_m_000000_0 - Still unresolved after refreshing

Comment: – Saša Zejnilović - Updated the code,,,but still the suggestion didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated code:

    val rdd= spark.sparkContext.textFile("src/test/resources/datasets/CDH_Wellness.csv")

    val rddwithoutheader= rdd.filter(_ != header)

    val elements= rddwithoutheader.map(line => {
      val colarray = line.split(",")
      Array((colarray(0),colarray(4),colarray(5),colarray(10))).mkString(" ")
    })

      elements.saveAsTextFile("C:/Spark_Files/RDDWithCSVFile/Output")
  }
}
`
************* 

Updated the output path -C:/Spark_Files/RDDWithCSVFile/Output , but still then its creating the earlier directory

C:\Spark_Files\RDDWithCSVFile\New Folder\_temporary
\0\_temporary\attempt_20200527112424_0006_m_000000_0

The RDD is not empty , the output file its creating is empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 C:\Spark_Files\RDDWithCSVFile\New Folder_temporary\0_temporary\attempt_20200527112424_0006_m_000000_0\part-00000

Error on console